# how to sort order of sapuit5 list?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I'm trying to display some items in a list in a specific order but I would like some orientation since I'm kind of new working with sap ui 5

Heres the code I have:

```
var oSelectMedioPago = new sap.m.Select({
                enabled: {
                    path: 'Enabled'
                },
                selectedKey: {
                    path: 'path'
                },
                items: {
                    path: "Items",
                    template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                        key: '{key}',
                        text: '{text}'
                    }),
                    templateShareable: false
                },
                change: function(oEvent) { 
//do something
});
```

How can I change the order of these items to be displayed by (for example) their property 'text' or something more general just like ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that! In binding items of the Select control just add a sorter as follows:

```html
items: {
                    path: "Items",

>                            sorter : {
>                            path : 'text' 
>                         },

                    template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                        key: '{key}',
                        text: '{text}'
                    }),
```

Here's a working example of a sorter using Northwind oData: http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/snippix/#63753

Learn about Sorting in SAPUI5 :[Sorting and Grouping](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c4b2a32bb72f483faa173e890e48d812)

Read more information on [sap.ui.model.Sorter](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Sorter)

Let me know if this helps:-)

Comment: please note that http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/snippix/#63753 is SAP internet website.